# failed to bind port in openstack-neutron

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

NOTE : I've seen this question and error being posted on different forums and in here, but none of them worked for me, and they belong to earlier versions of openstack. So, I posted a new question.

I've been setting up OpenStack Train based on its installation documents, and after setting up services, I tried to create a selfservice network using the instructions [here](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/launch-instance-networks-selfservice.html) but in "Verify Operation" section, step number 3, I see all of the ports are down :

```
[root@dev-openstack-controller ~]# openstack port list
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| ID                                   | Name | MAC Address       | Fixed IP Addresses                                                           | Status |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| 628ec286-90aa-4cca-92da-f698fb44a4e6 |      | fa:16:3e:a9:31:55 | ip_address='10.100.1.1', subnet_id='8d579a73-6951-445f-9905-51b9be2a6ff5'    | DOWN   |
| bb77b0d9-7ea8-47d3-b951-139a7616a4bd |      | fa:16:3e:89:52:37 | ip_address='203.0.113.166', subnet_id='0666d21c-0fd9-4caf-b560-f7d11e50cd83' | DOWN   |
| d2b684c9-eeee-47c4-ae12-dc97e19adf48 |      | fa:16:3e:cc:b8:3d | ip_address='10.100.1.2', subnet_id='8d579a73-6951-445f-9905-51b9be2a6ff5'    | DOWN   |
| fb7aff87-d083-4ed2-bf82-2ab4393373c7 |      | fa:16:3e:c8:a7:95 | ip_address='203.0.113.101', subnet_id='0666d21c-0fd9-4caf-b560-f7d11e50cd83' | DOWN   |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

First, I don't know why I see 4 ports instead of 2, and second, when I check neutron logs, I get the following error, which says it fails to bind port :

```
2020-04-18 11:05:12.321 25009 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.plugin [req-5c9c16a4-2327-4f46-b0ab-84e4e128d783 - - - - -] Attempt 10 to bind port 628ec286-90aa-4cca-92da-f698fb44a4e6
2020-04-18 11:05:12.347 25009 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.managers [req-5c9c16a4-2327-4f46-b0ab-84e4e128d783 - - - - -] Port 628ec286-90aa-4cca-92da-f698fb44a4e6 does not have an IP address assigned and there are no driver with 'connectivity' = 'l2'. The port cannot be bound.
2020-04-18 11:05:12.348 25009 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.managers [req-5c9c16a4-2327-4f46-b0ab-84e4e128d783 - - - - -] Failed to bind port 628ec286-90aa-4cca-92da-f698fb44a4e6 on host dev-openstack-controller.ershandc.org for vnic_type normal using segments [{'network_id': 'ae2b1f57-d91a-4ecd-ad15-2cc4b51a376f', 'segmentation_id': 45, 'physical_network': None, 'id': 'c28112f0-4f07-4f23-9f89-c3e37e68054c', 'network_type': u'vxlan'}]
```

I also get the same error for flat networks as well :

```
2020-04-18 11:05:11.107 25009 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.plugin [req-5c9c16a4-2327-4f46-b0ab-84e4e128d783 - - - - -] Attempt 10 to bind port bb77b0d9-7ea8-47d3-b951-139a7616a4bd
2020-04-18 11:05:11.135 25009 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.managers [req-5c9c16a4-2327-4f46-b0ab-84e4e128d783 - - - - -] Port bb77b0d9-7ea8-47d3-b951-139a7616a4bd does not have an IP address assigned and there are no driver with 'connectivity' = 'l2'. The port cannot be bound.
2020-04-18 11:05:11.136 25009 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.managers [req-5c9c16a4-2327-4f46-b0ab-84e4e128d783 - - - - -] Failed to bind port bb77b0d9-7ea8-47d3-b951-139a7616a4bd on host dev-openstack-controller.ershandc.org for vnic_type normal using segments [{'network_id': '25c5e314-e851-4a9c-ac7a-8e7b3e426deb', 'segmentation_id': None, 'physical_network': u'provider', 'id': '6dccf301-422b-41b9-b719-2999200126c6', 'network_type': u'flat'}]
```

I have tried different connectivities on ml2 plugin. Most of the cases relate to the following line in ml2_plugin.conf :

```
[ml2_type_flat]

flat_networks = flat
vni_ranges = 1:1000
```

Based on the openstack documentation, it should be `flat` but I've tried `*` as well and it didn't work.

Can someone elaborate the problem for me? I'm installing on a CentOS 7 VM. Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite dated question, but nevertheless I encountered the same situation hence let me post this anyway.

As the log says "no driver with 'connectivity' = 'l2'", the problem was in ml2_conf.ini. In my case, whole driver definitions were in [DEFAULT] section. I moved them to the proper location [ml2], everything started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I tried OpenStack, and finally I know the answer to the problem, which might help some people:

For setting up neutron, you need to have your internal network being set up in [promiscuous mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20networking%2C%20promiscuous%20mode,that%20the%20controller%20is%20specifically). I've been using VMWare for the setup and I did not have access to setup the VSwitch in this mode, also was not approved by our security auditor and there were other priorities to take care of, so I had to drop the project. But I found out that this post is getting attention and shogoK answer did not work for me, so with some research and getting a helping hand from some network expert, problem was identified. Hope this clue helps someone in the community.